# How to create a measure that takes part of column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I load a monthly data from a text file every month. In the table, there is a column that has string values with some extra strings with a fixed length. So the column looks like the following:

```
**OriginalColumn** 
String1_XXXXX
String2_XXXXX 
...
StringN_XXXXX
```

I would like to get rid of this extra fixed length string from the original column and I can do that by creating a new column something like:

```
NewColumn = LEFT(OriginalColumn,LEN(OriginalColumn)-6)
```

I am looking for a way to create a measure instead of a column. This is because as this is a monthly process that I would like to reduce the manual operation every month to create a new column. If using a measure, only data can be replaced.

Is there any way to do that? I have not found a measure that is working. When I create a measure  I always need to wrap a column that has string values with some function such as MAX(SomeColumn). I always thought there should be a better way.

Would somebody kindly advise?

Thanks & Regards,
Kyoto

Comment: Please provide some example, what your desired output is; How it should work across few month

Comment: Why you would create a new column each month, but not creating a new measure?

Comment: My desired monthly operation will be just loading data. I would like to use my existing measures for the newly loaded data and avoid creating new columns. For some cases such as trimming string column, creating a measure to do that seems impossible. Is there any way? Please kindly let me know if more clarification/information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a calculated column or a new measure, this can be done in a power query editor to remove the fixed length string from the original column before loading it into your model.

Comment: Hi BOUBRIT. Thanks a lot. You are right. After reading Power BI document etc. I've reached to the same conclusion. It's nice that experts responded to such a basic question like mine. I appreciate it.